# Outbound Gateway post request to spring MVC controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-integration

I have try to sent payload that have type **MultiValueMap** to spring MVC controller via Outbound gateway. But it seem to be that map data not coming to the controller. Don't know what is wrong or missing. and my code is be like this:

**Outbound config:**

```
 <int-http:outbound-gateway id="outGateway"
    http-method="POST"
    request-channel="responseChannel"
    url="http://localhost:8081/SpringIntegration-In-out-test/responseReq"
    extract-request-payload="true">
 </int-http:outbound-gateway>
```

**Controller Config:**

```
@RequestMapping("/responseReq")
public ModelAndView goResponse(@RequestBody MultiValueMap<String,String> body){

    Iterator  it = body.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        MultiValueMap.Entry pairs = (MultiValueMap.Entry)it.next();
        System.out.println(pairs.getKey() + " = " + pairs.getValue());
        it.remove(); 
    }
    return new ModelAndView("response");
}
```

I use Iterator to get map value but it have nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Eveything looks good.

1. I recommend you to 'sniff' your HTTP traffic and take a look what's going on with your body. On Windows I use T[CP Trace](http://www.tcptrace.org). Here you should be sure that you really send a `Map` as payload.
2. From other side test your `Controller` separately, e.g. using some RestClient. My preference - [Firefox plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/restclient). Build here the form manually, which should be converted to the `MultiValueMap` in the `DispatcherServlet` and don't forget to present header `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Answer (score 0):

If your outbound adapter is to be used in a unidirectional way (send-only), you should use `outbound-channel-adapter` :

```
<int-http:outbound-channel-adapter
    id="outAdapter"
    channel="responseChannel"
    url="http://localhost:8081/SpringIntegration-In-out-test/responseReq"
    http-method="POST"
    charset="UTF-8"
/>
```

Secondly, make your request mapping more precise by defining `RequestMethod` as `POST`:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/responseReq", method=RequestMethod.POST)
```

Lastly, why you are converting your Spring Integration Message into JMS Message by setting `extract-request-payload="true"`.